# Sql server 2005 - Returning data as XML or datatables

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have three classes

a) Parent - Which contains some properties, an Item collection and a collection of children

b) Child  - Which contains some properties and an Item collection

c) Item   - Which contains some properties

The relationship is depicted in the below XML structure.

```
<Parents>
    <Parent1>
        <Property1></Property1>
        <Property2></Property2>
        <Property3></Property3>
            <Parent1Children>
                <Child1>
                <Child1Property1></Child1Property1>
                <Child1Property2></Child1Property2>
                </Child1>
                <Child2>
                <Child2Property1></Child2Property1>
                <Child2Property2></Child2Property2>
                </Child2>
            </Parent1Children>  
        <Parent1SomeCollection>
            <Item1>
                <Item1Property1></Item1Property1>
                <Item1Property2></Item1Property2>
            </Item2>
            <Item2>
                <Item2Property1></Item2Property1>
                <Item2Property2></Item2Property2>
            </Item2>
        </Parent1SomeCollection>    
    </Parent1>  
</Parents>
```

I need to use the data from the tables of the three classes above. I can think of the following options:-

1. Get this structure in the form of
   XML from the database as depicted
   above from a stored procedure and
   use the same as XDocument in the
   business layer.
2. Get in the form of 3 tables from the
   database them in datatable and
   establish relationship between the
   to get the data?

Which one would give optimum performance and is a better way or are there better ways to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DataSet would hold the data better (assuming you're referring to .NET code), and maintain the relationships, while allowing you the ability to save the data in XML, and perform mass inserts and updates. So performance should be very good. Using an ORM would also be a good idea, since the ORM would give yous similar functionality, plus it may support LINQ (ORMs like Entity Framework and Linq-to-SQL).

Comment: +1 However, I don't intend to update data in this XML. This would be a read-only structure. Thats one reason why I don't think I should create a datatable. Could you please throw some light here If I cant see the obvious?

Comment: The DataSet / DataTable (DataSet supports the 1:N relationships you show, DataTables don't) is what a SqlCommand objects return, so no casting or translating the data types. You don't have to use it for updates / inserts. You may even be able to mark it as read-only. Plus the .WriteXml method will generate the XML data structure for you.